# How to run repeated test steps in pytest python

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

In my pytest test I have to run same verification step "verify()" and reset step "reset()", multiple times after different test steps . Is there a better way to handle this scenario:

e.g

```
class testval(object):
test1()
verify()
reset()
test2()
verify()
reset()
test3()
verify()
reset()
close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what verify() and reset() are performing. `reset()` I am assuming reseting the testing environment for each test case. If yes, you can use `setUp()` method after inheriting you testval class from `unittest.Testcase`. `verify()` I assume is some kind of assertion which can be used inside `test1()` itself like `self.assertTrue(1,1)`.

You can use `tearDown()` method to clear down the environment created by `setUp()`.
The thumb rule is to create testcase idempotent.